# Add a New Column with ALIASES on 'date' by automation based on search results

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mariadb, pivot, mariadb-10.2

I am trying to create a new column based on date search result.

I have written a code in the link SQL fiddle as I am looking for date automation on each column based on the date format. the date format Coloum can be up to 7 column or less or more, just based on how many dates in the record.

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/1)

Here is a screenshot as I would like to get this similar and the data is based on the number of sold SKU.

[image]

Comment: Please explain. Do you want a column for each date in the results? Also, what version do you use?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I am looking for a date on the header, let me edit it again to clear explanation.

Comment: Sory I'm using MySQL 5.5 with a version of  MariaDB 10

Comment: So you are using both (MariaDB 10 and MySQL 5.5) in different servers? OK.

Comment: yep, for now, i am using MySQL in the localhost.

Comment: I think I found what I am looking for https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205551/dynamic-dates-pivot

Comment: Yes, you need a (dynamic SQL) pivot. But that question is for SQL Server. Look for a MySQL one with pivot.

Comment: See Taryn's answer here: [MySQL single table static and dynamic pivot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27659/mysql-single-table-static-and-dynamic-pivot)

Comment: And this one: [Display Monthly Attendance Report in MySql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45995/display-monthly-attendance-report-in-mysql/46085#46085)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update status:-

As got advice and helpful from @ypercube

so far I got sorted with Fix static Pivot table but not dynamic Pivot table,

Here is a Static pivot table

```
    SELECT 
    ls.sku                                AS list_sku, 
    COALESCE( MIN(suo.sku), 'Not Sold' )  AS sold_sku, 
    SUM(CASE suo.date WHEN '2018-04-30' THEN units_ordered ELSE 0 END) AS Monday,
    SUM(CASE suo.date WHEN '2018-05-01' THEN units_ordered ELSE 0 END) AS Tuesday,
    SUM(CASE suo.date WHEN '2018-05-02' THEN units_ordered ELSE 0 END) AS Wednesday,
    SUM(CASE suo.date WHEN '2018-05-03' THEN units_ordered ELSE 0 END) AS Thursday,
    COALESCE( SUM(suo.units_ordered), 0 ) AS total_sold 
 FROM   tbl_list_sku AS ls
       LEFT JOIN tbl_sku_units_order AS suo 
              ON suo.sku = ls.sku 
GROUP  BY ls.sku 
ORDER  BY total_sold DESC ;
```

Here is output results

[image]

So far I will update  this answers when I got a fix with Dynamic table

**Update:** Got fix with Dynamic Pivot Table and please with it

```
    SET
   @sql = NULL;
SELECT
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'MAX(IF(suo.date = ''', date, ''', suo.units_ordered, 0)) AS ', CONCAT("`", date, "`") ) ) INTO @sql 
FROM
   tbl_sku_units_order;
SET
   @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ls.sku AS "List SKU", 
 COALESCE( MIN(suo.sku), "Not Sold" ) AS "sold_sku", ', @sql, ' , COALESCE( SUM(suo.units_ordered), 0 ) AS total_sold 
FROM
   tbl_list_sku AS ls 
   LEFT JOIN
      tbl_sku_units_order AS suo 
      ON suo.sku = ls.sku 
GROUP BY
   ls.sku 
ORDER BY
   total_sold DESC');
 PREPARE stmt 
FROM
   @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here is a result

[image: Pivot Table Result]

I know I'm not great code in the world, but delight with results and thank for your help @ypercube.